# Android Studio can't build Google Protobuf generated files

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

I have been working with google protocol buffers in this project for about 6 months now. All of a sudden out of no where I started getting errors when building my android project.

Error:(873, 45) error: cannot find symbol method writeString(CodedOutputStream,int,Object)

Error:(876, 77) error: cannot find symbol method getRaw(int)

Error:(886, 53) error: cannot find symbol method computeStringSize(int,Object)

Error:(891, 54) error: cannot find symbol method getRaw(int)

Error:(1938, 47) error: cannot find symbol method writeString(CodedOutputStream,int,Object)

Error:(1952, 55) error: cannot find symbol method computeStringSize(int,Object)

Error:(4605, 45) error: cannot find symbol method writeString(CodedOutputStream,int,Object)

Error:(4636, 53) error: cannot find symbol method computeStringSize(int,Object)

My build.grade 
looks like

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/GraphView-4.0.1.jar')
}
```

When I run proton --version it says 3.0.0

Up until a day ago everything was building. What did I do and how do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you were on an earlier version yesterday? Proto3 is alpha, so you might try to downgrade again.

Comment: That was it. They moved to beta a couple days ago and I got out of sync!!! Thank you. If you post it in an answer Ill give you the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you upgraded to [Proto3](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview), which has some breaking changes. If this is the case you might try to downgrade again and that should solve your problem.